# Не можу залишити питання на сайті

Tags: support

Намагаюся залишити питання, але сайт його не пропускає. Отримую оце:[image]

Що я роблю не так?

Or should I write in English?

Comment: Так, схоже, додавання англійських слів дозволяє позбутись цього повідомлення

Comment: Таке бувало з багатьма: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35747981#35747981

Answer (score 2):

до речі, як тільки додав фразу англійською, так одразу й розмістилося питання. А до цього не хотіло публікуватися, хоч плач!